# Eigenfunction and their orthogonality with respect to the weight function

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, inner-products, orthogonality

The Eigenfunction and their orthogonality with respect to the weight function $\sigma$ is defined as
$$\int_{a}^{b}\phi _n\text{(x)}\phi _m\text{(x)$\sigma $(x)dx=0}$$

Given that I have some function

$$
g(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\beta_n}\tanh\left( \frac{n\pi L}{H} \right)\sin\left( \frac{n\pi y}{H} \right)
$$

How should I go about finding what $$\beta_n$$ is using the properties of the eigenfunction and their orthogonality?
This is in the context of PDEs and the Sturm-Lioville problem.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that you have found this expansion by solving the sturm louville equation with weight function $\sigma =1$. In which case, the $\tanh(\ldots)\sinh(\ldots)$ are the riven functions, since they are orthonormal, taking an inner product with the $m$-th eigenfunction would yield $$\beta_m=-\int_0^Lg(x)\tanh(m\pi L/H)\sin(m\pi L/H)\,dx.$$
If the weight function is not $1$ it would also sit in the integral.

Comment: Hi ellya, yes, I arrived at the expansion by solving a heat equation (but it is not a SL problem).
The equation is 
$$U_{\text{xx}}+U_{\text{yy}}\text{=0}$$
With IC:
$$U(0,y)=g(y)$$
$$U(L,y)=0$$
$$U(X,0)=0$$
$$U(x,H)=0$$

For a non-SL problem, and by this I mean a homogenous PDE with homogenous BC, is is the weight function $$w(x)=1$$?
And yes, very impressive for you to have deduce backwards.